# Slow making many aggregate queries to a very large SQL Server table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance

I have a custom log/transaction table that tracks my users every action within the web application and it currently has millions of records and grows by the minute. In my application I need to implement some of way of precalculating a user's activities/actions in sql to determine whether other features/actions are available to the user within the application. For one example, before a page loads, I need to check if the user viewed a page X number of times.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyLog WHERE UserID = xxx and PageID = 123)
```

I am making several similar aggregate queries with joins for checking other conditions and the performance is poor. These checks are occuring on every page request and the application can receive hundreds of requests per minute.

I'm looking for any ideas to improve the application performance through sql and/or application code.

This is a .NET 2.0 app and using SQL Server 2008.

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: You could look into indexed views to precalculate the aggregates grouped by `UserId,PageId` but it sounds like the maintenance cost of these might be quite high as well with continual inserts.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to store the counts in a table by themselves. Then, when adding records (hopefully through an SP), you can simply increment the affected row in your aggregate table. If you are really worried about the counts getting out of whack, you can put a trigger on the detail table to update the aggregated table, however I don't like triggers as they have very little visibility.

Also, how up to date do these counts need to be? Can this be something that can be stored into a table once a day?

Comment: This is not trivial: if there are many incoming updates (which is probably the case for a large log) then you're going to have trouble doing atomic counters efficiently. Every update should happen in the context of a transaction and with multiple updates pinging the same rows concurrently the write throughput is going to be very low.

Comment: @Elad - If done correctly there should be row locking, there is no reason for the locks to get escalated. Even with many transactions, as long as it's not the same user (and it can't be, by nature of the problem) this should work fine.

Comment: @Mike-M By definition, the same affected row in the aggregate table needs to be updated very frequently. If a big enough number of rows are coming in concurrently that trigger an update to the aggregate table row then there's going to be lock contention and system performance will go down.

Comment: @Elad - I think we both have different ideas of what the aggregate table might look like. I was meaning to tie the count by both the Page and the User. Therefore, the only locking that would be done is if the same user was viewing the same page very quickly.

Comment: @Mike-M I apologize. You're right. I didn't pay enough attention when I read Todd's question and I was thinking about aggregation per page, not per both page and user.

Answer (score 1):

Querying a log table like this may be more trouble then it is worth.

As an alternative I would suggest using something like memcache to store the value as needed. As long as you update the cache on each hit it will much faster the querying a large database table. Memcache has an build in increment operator that handles this kind of thing.
This way you only need to query the db on the first visit.

Another alternative is to use a precomputed table, updating it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed MyLog on UserID and PageID?  If not, that should give you some huge gains.

Comment: Yes and it did significantly improve execution time. However performance is still not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Todd this is a tough one because of the number of operations you are performing.
Have you checked your indexes on that database?

Here's a stored procedure you can execute to help at least find valid indexes.  I can't remember where I found this but it helped me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SQLMissingIndexes]
@DBNAME varchar(100)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) 
        * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure, 
        'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' 
        + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) 
        + '_' + CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle) 
        + '_' + LEFT (PARSENAME(mid.statement, 1), 32) + ']'
        + ' ON ' + mid.statement 
        + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'') 
        + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL 
          AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END 
        + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
        + ')' 
        + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement,
        migs.*, 
        mid.database_id, 
        mid.[object_id]
    FROM 
        sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs 
    ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid 
    ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
    WHERE 
        migs.avg_total_user_cost 
        * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) 
        * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10
    AND 
        (@DBNAME = db_name(mid.database_id) OR @DBNAME IS NULL)
ORDER BY 
        migs.avg_total_user_cost 
        * migs.avg_user_impact 
        * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
END
```

I modified it a bit to accept a db name.  If you dont provide a db name it will run and give you information about all databases and give you suggestions on what fields need indexing.

To run it use:

`exec DatabaseName.dbo.SQLMissingIndexes 'MyDatabaseName'`

I usually put reusable SQL (Sproc) code in a seperate database called `DBA` then from any database I can say:

exec `DBA.dbo.SQLMissingIndexes`

As an example.

## Edit

Just remembered the source, Bart Duncan.
Here is a direct link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx

But remember I did modify it to accept a single db name.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, beginning several years ago, moved from SQL Server to OLAP cubes, and when that stopped working recently we moved again, to Hadoop and some other components.

OLTP (Online Transaction Processing) databases, of which SQL Server is one, are not very good at OLAP (Online Analytical Processing). This is what OLAP cubes are for.

OLTP provides good throughput when you're writing and reading many individual rows. It fails, as you just found, when doing many aggregate queries that require scanning many rows. Since SQL Server stores every record as a contiguous block on the disk, scanning many rows means many disk fetches. The cache saves you for a while - so long as your table is small, but when you get to tables with millions of rows the problem becomes evident.

Frankly, OLAP isn't that scalable either, and at some point (tens of millions of new records per day) you're going to have to move to a more distributed solution - either paid (Vertica, Greenplum) or free (HBase, Hypertable).

If neither is an option (e.g. no time or no budget) then for now you can alleviate your pain somewhat by spending more on hardware. You need very fast IO (fast disks, RAID), as as much RAM as you could get.